# How to perform indexed searches for 2 arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, indexing

I have about 30 million documents, which have two lists of values, which I need to search for co-occurrence of specific combinations. I was first tempted to use 2 arrays and a compound index, but these can hold only a single array element. Can anyone help me to restructure my documents to allow such an indexed search?

I am using Python dictionaries on the application side, so I would prefer a document structure, which is compliant to this restriction.

Simplified example:

```
{
    Id:1,
    List1: ['a','b'],
    List2: ['c','d]
}
```

A query would then e.g. search for all documents with an 'a' in list1 and a 'd' in list2.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/#limitations). Indexes cannot be created over a document containing two arrays in the compound key. This is a common design mistake. What you really need is a single list keyed by type `List: [{ "t": "l1", "v"; "a" },{ "t": "l1", "v": "b" },{ "t": "l2", "v": "c" },{ "t": "l2", "v": "d" }]`.

Comment: Obviously I had read the documentation after finding out that 2 arrays did not work, but thanks for sharing the link. Nevertheless, thanks for your implication with a typed list. I see that this should work to resolve the indexing struggles I had. However, this will make the documents more difficult to access visually. Is there maybe a different way like having sub-documents under the Lists and checking for the existence of keys in an index-based manner?

Comment: I cannot see why it would be more difficult to access. This actually was a similar trap that I fell into when first using MongoDB, since I too thought storing multiple arrays in my documents was what I needed and a good idea. From experience I know better now. You pretty much always want a single array denoted in such a way or you store in a separate collection if the structure requires updating multiple elements at once. Your requirements as stated in the question are really quite simple. So you either express what you really need to do without being abstract or try to apply and then ask.

Comment: Of course I was trying to simplify the problem as much as possible. In reality I will have 7 lists with quite diverse meanings of the items. Therefore a grouping within the JSON format under a speaking label seem easier for me to access visually. Yes, I can query only those items from a typed list, by filtering the respective type. 
For now I will probably just add a list in the way you suggested and index over it.

Comment: The solution is working for me. Thank you.